# C# return with a variable and a SINGLE equals sign in it

Tags: c#

I found this in a project I inherited.  It works, but I don't understand the return.  Anyone have an explanation for what it does?

```
DataTable resultTable = GetTemplate();
string sql = "select * from table1";
return resultTable = dataAccessLayer.Read(readSql);
```

I've never seen a single equals sign in a return statement and my google foo is apparently weak today...

Comment: when you assign a variable with a = sign the value will be returned as well for example this is valid c# `var a ="";
(a="lkj").First()`. but the code looks strange like something was deleted because resultTable is useless and the assignment doesn't do anything.

Comment: A little bit opinionated, but if I were to review this, I'd actually suggest to change it. For one it's a terrible read and second, I suspect it is buggy.